# Idiomatic way to implement UPSERT in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, upsert

I've read about different `UPSERT` implementations in PostgreSQL, but all of these solutions are relatively old or relatively exotic (using [writeable CTE](http://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/upsertmerge-using-writable-cte-in-postgresql-9-1/), for example).

And I'm just not a psql expert at all to find out immediately, whether these solutions are old because they are well recommended or they are (well, almost all of them are) just toy examples not appropriate to production use.

What is the most thread-safe way to implement UPSERT in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PostgreSQL now has [UPSERT](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT).

---

The preferred method according [a similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql) is currently the following:

```
CREATE TABLE db (a INT PRIMARY KEY, b TEXT);

CREATE FUNCTION merge_db(key INT, data TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- first try to update the key
        UPDATE db SET b = data WHERE a = key;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        -- not there, so try to insert the key
        -- if someone else inserts the same key concurrently,
        -- we could get a unique-key failure
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO db(a,b) VALUES (key, data);
            RETURN;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            -- do nothing, and loop to try the UPDATE again
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT merge_db(1, 'david');
SELECT merge_db(1, 'dennis');
```

Comment: I'd rather use a writeable CTE: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8702291/330315

Comment: What's the advantage of a writable CTE vs a function?

Comment: @François for one thing, speed.  Using a CTE you hit the database once.  Doing it this way you might hit it two or more times.  Also, the optimizer can't optimize pl/pgsql procedures as efficiently as pure SQL code.

Comment: @François For another thing, concurrency. Since the above example has multiple SQL statements you have to worry about race conditions (the reason for the klugey loop). A single SQL statement will be atomic.  See [this link](http://www.xzilla.net/blog/2011/Mar/Upserting-via-Writeable-CTE.html)

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17267423/533832) and [here](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/) for why. Basically without a re-try loop, you either have to serialize or you have the possibility of failures due to the inherent race condition.

Comment: Writing a stored procedure for every table and combination of fields is a non-starter.  The answer from @JoshuaBurns is much better.

Comment: @AdamMackler I think your concern for concurrency is unfounded. The `merge_db` function would run in the transactional context of the calling `SELECT` statement, so it would be atomic.

Answer (score 29):

***UPDATE*** (2015-08-20):

There is now an official implementation for handling upserts through the use of [`ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) (official documentation). At the time of this writing, this feature currently resides in PostgreSQL 9.5 Alpha 2, which is available for download here: [Postgres source directories](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/).

Here is an example, assuming `item_id` is your Primary Key:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
    (item_id, price)
VALUES
    (123456, 10.99)
ON
    CONFLICT (item_id)
DO UPDATE SET
    price = EXCLUDED.price
```

Original Post...

Here is an implementation I arrived upon when desiring to gain visibility into whether an insert or update occurred.

The definition of `upsert_data` is to consolidate the values into a single resource, rather than having to specify the price and item_id twice: Once for the update, again for the insert.

```
WITH upsert_data AS (
    SELECT
    '19.99'::numeric(10,2) AS price,
    'abcdefg'::character varying AS item_id
),
update_outcome AS (
    UPDATE pricing_tbl
    SET price = upsert_data.price
    FROM upsert_data
    WHERE pricing_tbl.item_id = upsert_data.item_id
    RETURNING 'update'::text AS action, item_id
),
insert_outcome AS (
    INSERT INTO
        pricing_tbl
    (price, item_id)
    SELECT
        upsert_data.price AS price,
        upsert_data.item_id AS item_id
    FROM upsert_data
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT item_id FROM update_outcome LIMIT 1)
    RETURNING 'insert'::text AS action, item_id
)
SELECT * FROM update_outcome UNION ALL SELECT * FROM insert_outcome
```

If you don't like the use of `upsert_data`, here is an alternate implementation:

```
WITH update_outcome AS (
    UPDATE pricing_tbl
    SET price = '19.99'
    WHERE pricing_tbl.item_id = 'abcdefg'
    RETURNING 'update'::text AS action, item_id
),
insert_outcome AS (
    INSERT INTO
        pricing_tbl
    (price, item_id)
    SELECT
        '19.99' AS price,
        'abcdefg' AS item_id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT item_id FROM update_outcome LIMIT 1)
    RETURNING 'insert'::text AS action, item_id
)
SELECT * FROM update_outcome UNION ALL SELECT * FROM insert_outcome
```

Comment: How does it perform?

Comment: @jb. not as well as I would like. You're going to see significant performance penalties vs. performing straight inserts. However for smaller batches (say 1000 or less,) this example should perform just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will let you know whether the insert or update happened:

```
with "update_items" as (
  -- Update statement here
  update items set price = 3499, name = 'Uncle Bob'
  where id = 1 returning *
)
-- Insert statement here
insert into items (price, name)
-- But make sure you put your values like so
select 3499, 'Uncle Bob'
where not exists ( select * from "update_items" );
```

If the update occurs, you'll get an insert 0, otherwise insert 1 or an error.