# Call UPSERT function multiple times to different inputs

Tags: postgresql, functions, upsert

I have a function:

```
merge_vehicles(vid, cid, vname, reg_no, name, name_1st)
```

Can i call it multiple times on inputs like

```
(2335, 55, '246BDH', '246BDH', '811', 1),
(2336, 55, '038THX', '038THX', '831', 1),
....
```

The function is an **`UPSERT`** implementation returning `void`. This is meant to be a warehouse database (fact table). We have a live database that gets more than 1000 inputs per hour. We want to use this command to merge our data with the new data.

It is a table function. (I have defined alike functions to every table we have - that's 5.) Result is, it will update existing rows, if they exist, otherwise inserts new row.

Postgres version is 9.3.

Function is a version of the accepted answer here:

- [Idiomatic way to implement UPSERT in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/most-idiomatic-way-to-implement-upsert-in-postgresql-nowadays)

Comment: Obviously, you have to give more details. Is it a table-function? How is the return type defined? In what context? What is the desired result?  Your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### UPSERT 1 row at a time with function

A "table-function" is a function returning a set of rows (acting like a table when called with `SELECT * FROM myfunc()`). What you have is *not* a table-function. Since nothing is returned you can use a simple call:

```
SELECT merge_vehicles(vid, cid, vname, reg_no, name, name_1st)
FROM  (
   VALUES
     (2335, 55, '246BDH', '246BDH', '811', 1::numeric) -- example for explicit cast
    ,(2336, 55, '038THX', '038THX', '831', 1)
    , ...
   ) t(vid, cid, vname, reg_no, name, name_1st)        -- arbitrary column names
```

While that *works*, upserting 1 row at a time is **very inefficient** for big sets.

#### Bulk UPSERT

Assuming `(vid, cid)` is the primary key of our table `test` (information missing), I suggest a data-modifying CTE for the UPSERT after taking out an `EXCLUSIVE LOCK` on the table.

The `EXCLUSIVE LOCK` still allows concurrent transactions to read from the table, but no writes. It is only necessary if you actually *can* have concurrent transactions writing to the same table.

```
BEGIN;

LOCK TABLE test IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

-- Or use a temp table for new rows. See below.
WITH my_rows(vid, cid, vname, reg_no, name, name_1st) AS (
   VALUES
      (2335, 55, '246BDH', '246BDH', '811', 1::numeric) -- example for explicit cast
     ,(2336, 55, '038THX', '038THX', '831', 1)
     , ...
   )
, upd AS (
    UPDATE test t
    SET   (  vname,   reg_no,   name,   name_1st)
        = (m.vname, m.reg_no, m.name, m.name_1st)
    FROM   my_rows m
    WHERE  t.vid = m.vid        -- match on PK columns
    AND    t.cid = m.cid
    RETURNING t.vid, t.cid      -- return only PK columns
    )
INSERT INTO test
      (  vid,   cid,   vname,   reg_no,   name,   name_1st)
SELECT m.vid, m.cid, m.vname, m.reg_no, m.name, m.name_1st
FROM   my_rows m
LEFT   JOIN upd USING (vid, cid)
WHERE  u.vid IS NULL;           -- only remaining rows

COMMIT;                         -- releases all locks
```

If the list is long, consider a **temp table populated with `COPY`** to replace the CTE `my_rows` and its `VALUES` expression.

Related:

- [Issue with composite type in an UPSERT function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33319/issue-with-composite-type-in-an-upsert-function/33322#33322)
- [How do I do an UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT … ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267423/939860)
- [Optimizing bulk update performance in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41059/optimizing-bulk-update-performance-in-postgresql/41111#41111)
- [Generate DEFAULT values in a CTE UPSERT using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797357/939860)

#### Call set-returning function multiple times in one SELECT

<sup>(Before update to the question)</sup>

Assuming we are dealing with a set-returning function (a.k.a. "table-function").

You can use a `VALUES` expression for literal input of a derived table of parameters (or any other derived or actual table in its place) and conveniently use a `LATERAL JOIN` (Postgres 9.3+) to get the united results in one query. You may want to order in some way ...

```
SELECT f.*
FROM  (
   VALUES
     (2335, 55, '246BDH', '246BDH', '811', 1::numeric) -- example for explicit cast
    ,(2336, 55, '038THX', '038THX', '831', 1)
    , ...
   ) t(vid, cid, vname, reg_no, name, name_1st)        -- arbitrary column names
     , merge_vehicles(vid, cid, vname, reg_no, name, name_1st) f;
```

The `LATERAL JOIN` is implicit with function calls in the `FROM` list. More details here:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

Numeric literals in this example default to type `integer` and string literals become `text`. Add explicit casts if you need specific types.

Comment: The function returns void and it is a `upsert` implementation. This is meant to be a warehouse database (fact table). We have a live database, that gets more than 1000 inputs per hour. We want to use this command to merge our data and that new data

Comment: @DaddyStrikes: That's a completely different problem, then. Consider the new answer.

Comment: As I'm not really familiar with CTE or complex SQL sentences, Thanks! It was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can call the function multiple times like the following

```
select merge_vehicles (2335, 55, '246BDH', '246BDH', '811', 1);
select merge_vehicles (2336, 55, '038THX', '038THX', '831', 1);
```

Comment: I though of I myself, but it aint gonna dig for my problem